# Check if object have attribute with codecontracts

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I have method in factory class

```
    internal Window GetWindow(int siteId)
    {
        Contract.Requires(siteId > 0);

        Window result;

        //some logic that create specific window

        return result;
    }
```

Lets assume i have `[MyAttribute]`

I need postcondition in `GetWindow` which can prove that method returns object marked with `[MyAttribute]`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible with reflection.

I'm assuming that the method you want to test is in the same class.

```
   Type returnedType = this.GetType().GetMethod("The method you want to test").ReturnType;
   Contract.Requires(returnedType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true).Length > 0);
```